# Как работать с content-скриптом в chrome расширении?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, расширения

Всем привет. Решил разобраться в написании расширений для браузера, поискал в интернете, но немного не понял, как работать с контент-скриптом. На сколько я понял, этот скрипт исполняется будто он находится в самой веб-странице. Но почему-то, например, простейший alert(); не выполняется. В чём ошибка?

Код:
manifest.json:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

popup.html:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

popup.js:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

content_script.js:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а без обработчика выполняется (без chrome.runtime.onMessage..) ?

Comment: Разместите код в виде текста, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Для отправки сообщения из popup или background вам необходимо воспользоваться методом [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage). Именно он отвечает за доставку сообщений внутрь контент-скрипта, выполняющегося на страница. 

Для этого метода необходимо указать ID таба. Его 
можно получить, допустим, методом [`chrome.tabs.query`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query).

Также, обратите внимание на то, что код вида:

```html
<button OnClick="start()">Button</button>
```

..не будет работать, по причине того, что в расширениях запрещено исполнение *inline javascript*. Вам необходимо разместить JS код в отдельном файле и подключить его к popup.html через тег script.